# Store char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

another c++ question.

I use a libary to receive data from a webservice. Everytime I get content a method named OnData is called.

```
void OnData(const Response* r, void* userdata,
    const unsigned char* data, int n) { //code here }
```

the const unsigned char* data is what contains the data I want. But OnData was called multiple times. So I thought I'd use a string and just append it with that data. I got no compile errors so I was expecting it to work. But when I received errors I made an output of the stirng I noticed I only got like 15% of my expected data.

After that I've been searching for a while now on the internet looking for a way I could safe all that data in some kind of array.

Something extra, I need to have a char pointer to send through to my xml parser. So if there is a way I can get all that data in a nice char pointer it would help alot.

Comment: you could just use a generic array class like Array<char>. i think you can use things like the boost library or the stl (standard template library), which maybe comes with your compiler as c++-script.

Comment: Maybe the data contains embedded null characters?  This would stop any std::string-like buffer you use to stop at that point.  In other words: what type of string did you use, and how do you fill it?

Comment: "I got no compile errors so I was expecting it to work." You have been spending too much time programming in Idris.

Comment: I used 
std::string completemsg;
completemsg.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data));

Comment: Better use the append(data, n) variant, because it smells like there's a null embedded in there if not all of the string comes over as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a copy with something like `std:string Mydata(data);` is probably the rigt way. You can store them in a `std::vector<std:string>`

Edit:

Since data is probably not zero terminated:

```
static std::vector<std:string> MyData;

MyData.emplace_back(data,n);
```

Or if you want to store all data in one string:

```
static std::string MyData;
MyData.append(data,n);
```

Comment: Won't do if data contains embedded null characters - better use the string constructor taking both a pointer and a size.

Comment: append(data,n) solved it.